# Running a large PHP process on a mobile "mini" browser

Tags: php, ajax, mobile, opera

My client keeps testing the script I made on his mobile browsers... and one of them is Opera "mini". At some point a process has to run for a few minutes, and I don't know how to deal with this on this browser. I wanted to show the progress at first, but at this point I just want any way to put the browser on hold until the process finishes and be notified when it does.

Things I know or tried:
- Opera mini doesn't support XMLHTTPRequest 2.0. So you can't get the progress that way.
- It supports timers but only for FIVE seconds... so you can't keep sending AJAX requests to check the progress.
- I tried to just send one AJAX request to do the job while simply waiting for the success callback, but it seems the browser times out an AJAX request after a long time.
- "Can't you divide the process in smaller parts?" you'd say. I was doing that, and reloading the page for each sub-run... until I realized the drawback: if you want to go back with the browser, you'll see 50 times the same page.

Is there any way of dealing with this?? I would appreciate any idea. Thanks!

Comment: 1) job writes status somewhere on a regular basis 2) server-side ajax handler reads that status 3) client requests that status periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I ran into a similar issue.  Making an Ajax Request will have 2 problems. 1st one, the navigator is going to be freezed. 2nd one, most servers will raise an error after some time runnning the script (30 seconds, usually, can be raised, in some scenarios).

The way I 1st dealt with it was to record relevant data in files and divide the process in smaller processes, and, on every success ajax response, relaunch next step until the task was ended, saving the % complete to a session variable on each request, as well as the current step of the processes to recover it, much like this:

```
function stepOnTask(){
  ajax.post("file.php", "action:doPartialTask", function(response){
    if ( response.taskFinished ) alert("Task Done"); 
    else{
      showProgress(response.currentProgress);
      stepOnTask();
    }});
}
```

But it was really intense for my desktop navigator and too often it crashed, not to say that you couldn´t do nothing meanwhile, so I changed it totally to another approach, using background processes in php and saving relevant information (estimated time, start time, and so on...) in a file named by the pid of the launched process, and make every x seconds a request to that file to check and show the progress.

That last point is a bit longer, and I won´t be posting code if you don´t ask me to, as I´m not sure that is the kind of solution you are looking for.

Good Luck.

**EDIT**

PHP Background Process Style

```
Class BackgroundScript{
    public $win_path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\www\\yourProject";
    public $unix_path = "/home/yourFolder/yourProject.com";
    public $script = NULL;
    public $command = NULL;
    public $pid = NULL;
    public $start_time = NULL;
    public $estimated_time = NULL;
    public $ellapsed_time = NULL;
    public $status_file = NULL;

    public function __construct($script = ""){
        $this->script = $script;
        if ( self::get_os() == "windows" ){
            $this->command = "start /b C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe ".$this->win_path."\\".$this->script;
        }else{
            $this->command = "php ".$this->unix_path."/".$this->script;
        }
    }

    public static function conPID($pid){
        if ( file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/pids/".$pid.".json") ){
            $bgScript = new BackgroundScript();
            $process_info = json_decode(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/pids/".$pid.".json"));
            foreach ( $process_info as $key=>$val ){
                $bgScript->$key = $val;
            }
            return $bgScript;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function get_os(){
        if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" ) return "windows";
        else return "unix";
    }

    public function saveToFile(){
        $path_to_pfolder = self::get_os()=="windows"? $this->win_path."\\pids":$this->unix_path."/pids";

        if ( !( file_exists($path_to_pfolder) && is_dir($path_to_pfolder)) ){
            mkdir($path_to_pfolder);
        }
        $fileHandler = fopen($path_to_pfolder."/".$this->pid.".json", "w");
        $this->status_file = $path_to_pfolder."/".$this->pid.".json";

        fwrite($fileHandler, json_encode($this));
        fclose($fileHandler);

        return $this->status_file;
    }

    public function removeFile(){
        $path_to_pfolder = self::get_os()=="windows"? $this->win_path."\\pids":$this->unix_path."/pids";
        unlink($path_to_pfolder."/".$this->pid.".json");
    }

    public function run($outputFile = '/dev/null'){
        if ( self::get_os() == "windows" ){
            $desc = array(
               0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin es una tubería usada por el hijo para lectura
               1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout es una tubería usada por el hijo para escritura
            );

            //proc_get_status devuelve el pid del proceso que lanza al proceso, o sea, del padre, y hay que hacer algo más para obtener el pid real del proceso que genera el archivo
            $p = proc_open($this->command, $desc, $pipes);
            $status = proc_get_status($p);
            $ppid = $status["pid"];

            //Ya tenemos el pid del padre, ahora buscamos el del último proceso hijo, que será el que acabamos de lanzar, y lo guardamos
            $output = array_filter(explode(" ", shell_exec("wmic process get parentprocessid,processid | find \"$ppid\"")));
            array_pop($output);
            $this->pid = end($output);

            //Cerramos el proceso padre, esto es lo que hará que no se nos quede pillada la aplicación mientras el "servidor" trabaja.
            proc_close($p);
        } else{
            //En unix e ma facilico
             $this->pid =  trim(shell_exec(sprintf('%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $!', $this->command,  $outputFile)));
        }
        $this->ellapsed_time = 0;
        $this->start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        return $this->saveToFile();
    }

    public function isRunning()
    {
        try {
            $result = shell_exec(sprintf('ps %d', $this->pid));
            if(count(preg_split("/\n/", $result)) > 2) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {}

        return false;
    }

    public function kill(){
        $this->removeFile();
        if ( self::get_os() == "windows" ){
            shell_exec(" taskkill /PID ".$this->pid);
        } else{
            // shell_exec(sprintf('kill %d 2>&1', $this->pid));
            shell_exec(sprintf('kill '.$this->pid));
        }
    }

    public function getPid(){
        return $this->pid;
    }

    public static function getAll(){
        $path_to_pfolder = self::get_os()=="windows"? self::$win_path."\\pids":self::$unix_path."/pids";

        if ( !( file_exists($path_to_pfolder) && is_dir($path_to_pfolder)) ){
            return array();
        }   
        $archivos = scandir($path_to_pfolder);
        $processes = array();

        foreach ($archivos as $archivo){
            if ( is_file($path_to_pfolder."/".$archivo) ){
                $json = file_get_contents($path_to_pfolder."/".$archivo);
                $info = json_decode($json);
                $process = new BackgroundScript();
                foreach ( $info as $key=>$val ){
                    $process->$key = $val;
                }
                $processes[] = $process;
            }
        }

        return $processes;
    }

    public function view(){
        $segundos_estimados = $this->estimated_time;
        $segundos_transcurridos = time() - strtotime($this->start_time);
        $segundos_restantes = max($segundos_estimados - $segundos_transcurridos, 0);

        /*
        $minutos_estimados = floor($segundos_estimados/60);
        $segundos_estimados = $segundos_estimados - $minutos_estimados*60;

        $minutos_restantes = floor($segundos_restantes/60);
        $segundos_restantes = $segundos_restantes - $minutos_restantes*60;
        */

        $estimado =  date("i:s", strtotime("1983-09-23 00:00:00")+$segundos_estimados);
        $restante = date("i:s", strtotime("1983-09-23 00:00:00")+$segundos_restantes);

        if (!$segundos_estimados){
            $html="<a>".$this->nombre_diario."
                    <!--<br>Tiempo Estimado: <span class='estimado'>Calculando</span>-->
                    <br>Tiempo Restante: <span class='restante' data-time='".$segundos_restantes."'>Calculando</span></a>";
        }elseif (!$segundos_transcurridos){
                $html="<a>".$this->nombre_diario."
                    <!--<br>Tiempo Estimado: <span class='estimado'>Guardando</span>-->
                    <br>Tiempo Restante: <span class='restante' data-time='".$segundos_restantes."'>Guardando</span></a>";
        }else{  
                $html="<a>".$this->nombre_diario."
                    <!--<br>Tiempo Estimado: <span class='estimado'>".$estimado."</span>-->
                    <br>Tiempo Restante: <span class='restante' data-time='".$segundos_restantes."'>".$restante."</span></a>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Ok, I understand the code may look a bit bad, but it works.

Now, I will show you the way I use it, you must adapt it to your own style.

I have a file called controller.php that handles all the actions in my project that looks much like this:

```
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST["action"]) ) $action= $_POST["action"];
else $action= $argv[1];

switch ($action) {
    case "performTask1":{   
       task1();
    }
    break;

    case "performTask2":{   
       task2();
    }
    break;

    case "performTask2inBackground":
    {
        $process = new BackgroundScript("controller.php performTask2");
        $response["file_with_info"] = $process->run();  
    }
    break;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

And that´s all.

Of course, at the beginning of the class you must change win_path and unix_path to match your own machine path to the project. I use both of them so my local test enviroment and real server version work the same. No mac version yet :P (Hope you don´t need it).

Another thing to note is that in the constructor you may have to change the path that builds the variable "command" if your php  folder is in a different path.

A directory called "pid" will be created at the root of the project to save the files with the information, having the name {pid_of_the_process}.json. Please, note that it´s up to you to fill this file with useful information in your process, if you don´t, it will not have useful information.

The proper way to do this would be, in your script, do something like that:

```
...
do{
   doLotsOfThings();
   $bgScript= BackgroundScript::conPID(getmypid());
   $bgScript->estimated_time = recalculate_estimated_time();
   $bgScript->ellapsed_time = recalculate_remaining_time();
   $bgScript->saveToFile();
 } while($whatever)
 //END
 $process->kill();
```

To retrieve at any point information about the running processes for any purpose you can use `BackgroundScript::getAll();`, to show a snapshot of the estimated remaining time for the procees, for example, that is why a left a "view" method, that may not be useful to you, but is what I use to retrieve the status and show the user the remaining time on demand.

For debugging purposes, I suggest you to locate the php error log file, much needed, as you won´t have direct browser feedback, and remember that you can simply paste the generated command in your console and run the process if you want first hand information of what´s going on.

Finally, I´d like to give credits to @FlorianEckerstorfer whose background-process library helped me to develop that solution I posted here.

Comment: For some reason, I hadn't thought of this, even when I've used it previously: divide in chunks and simply do a new AJAX call for every success response... so no timer involved and no long AJAX call. Thanks!

Comment: Deserves a Try, but too often it freezed Google Chrome on my superb computer, so not optimist with Opera mini, let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately... no, didn't work. Although I couldn't find confirmation anywhere, Opera mini seems to cancel any AJAX request after 5 seconds of the page being loaded. The browsers just refuses to use the processor in any way for longer than that time.

Comment: I´m going to post the code to call background process, it may help you, but it´s a bit large.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you send chunked response to user so that he keeps on seeing the result on his web page while the process continues to process new data.

```
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
//ob_end_flush();
while (@ob_end_flush());

// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush(true);
echo '
<table>
<thead>
<th>Url</th>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Class</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
ob_flush();
flush();
```

You can Google for further details on chuncked response.

Comment: Thanks. I've come across workarounds like this while researching. I hadn't used something like this before and I was wondering: this is used to always "append" HTML at the end of the document, right? But can you update a progress display somehow while doing it? (without timers)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This method will send data in chunks and is used to mainly give an illusion that the page is rendering fast. but if you do echo 'data'; ob_flush();flush(); in a for loop and along with data if you can update your client with the progress then it solves your problem. ex: foreach($data as $key => $item){echo $item . ' ' .$key .'% completed' ; ob_flush();flush();}.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need a server response, your page can try to load some 1x1px image. This img is php script what return this img and then reset the connection. But with ignore_user_abort(true) script can still continues working.